# How do you deal with IDs in Shiny Dropdown lists?

Tags: r, shiny

Typically in a web interface if you have a dropdown populated from a database that display's some text and you want to use that selected text in the dropdown and pass it back to a database. But a lot of times you want to pass an ID instead of the actual text displayed.

In my example below I have a global.R file that returns the data for the dropdowns. This simulates data returned from a database. For each dropdown there is a text field that is displayed in the dropdowns and an "id" field that is not displayed BUT I have to somehow access the "id" fields of the dropdowns. How is this done in Shiny?... Because the selectInputs don't allow you to store the ids so you can access them like input$DisplayName$id

In the example below I just want to print the "id" of the "DisplayName" selectInput so if "Mary" is in the input$DisplayName then "20" should be printed in the RenderText call.

Here is code to run:

```
require(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Department", "Select a department", choices = as.character(GetDepartments()$Department), selected = as.character(GetDepartments()$Department[1])),
      uiOutput("DisplayName")
    ),
    mainPanel(textOutput("Text") )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    output$DisplayName<-renderUI({
      Department <- input$Department
      print(Department)
      selectInput("DisplayName", 'DisplayName:', choices = as.character(GetDisplayName(Department)$DisplayName), selected =as.character(GetDisplayName(Department)$DisplayName[1] ))
    })


    output$Text <- renderText({

# Here I want to simulate accessing the "id" field of the input$DisplayName
#in my app I need to pass the id to a database query
#If Mary is in input$DisplayName how can I access her id of "20"?
      print("in render text") 

      return( ??? How do I access the id  = 20???) 
    })

  }
))
```

Here is the global.r file that simulates code that returns stuff from a database

```
GetDepartments<- function(){
  df<- data.frame(Department= c("Dept A", "Dept B"), id = c(1,2))
  return(df)
}

GetDisplayName<- function(Dept){
  if(Dept == "Dept A")
  {
    df<- data.frame(DisplayName= c("Bob", "Fred"), id = c(4,6))
    return(df)
  }else
  {
    df<- data.frame(DisplayName= c("George", "Mary"), id = c(10,20))
    return(df)
  }

}
```

Comment: Try this as the body of your `output$Text` function: `nameDf <- GetDisplayName(input$Department);
    Id <- subset(nameDf,DisplayName==input$DisplayName)$id;
    print(Id);
    return(Id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286674/how-to-use-external-columns-with-linked-output-in-shiny).  As @nrussel suggests, this is just a simple subsetting problem.  Just pull up your department and index on the name.  Here is a working example.

EDIT*** - make dataset reactive to avoid repetition.

As per the [documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/):

**Reactive expressions are a smarter than regular R functions. They cache results and only update when they become obsolete. The first time that you run a reactive expression, the expression will save its result in your computer’s memory. The next time you call the reactive expression, it can return this saved result without doing any computation (which will make your app faster). The reactive expression will use this new copy until it too becomes out of date.**

```
runApp(list(
    ui = basicPage(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Department", "Select a department", 
                        choices = as.character(GetDepartments()$Department), 
                        selected = as.character(GetDepartments()$Department[1])),
            uiOutput("DisplayName")
        ),
        mainPanel(textOutput("Text") )
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {

        myData <- reactive({
            GetDisplayName(input$Department)
        })

        output$DisplayName<-renderUI({
            Department <- input$Department
            print(Department)
            myData <- myData()
            selectInput("DisplayName", 'DisplayName:', choices = as.character(myData$DisplayName), 
                        selected =as.character(myData$DisplayName[1] ))
        })


        output$Text <- renderText({
            print("in render text") 
            myData <- myData()
            code <- as.character(myData[myData$DisplayName == input$DisplayName,2])
            return(code)       
        })

    }
))
```

Comment: cdeterman - I was hoping to avoid calling GetDisplayName(). This works but seems inefficient. Is there a way to just attach the ID to the "DisplayName"  selectInput? Right now if you change the "Department" selectInput GetDisplayName() is called to populate the dropdown and then called immediatley again to print the id.

Comment: @user3022875, see my edit, by making the dataset reactive, it can be called as needed.